# Creating IPHONE application with PHP,Possible?

Tags: php, iphone

I want to try to create an iPhone app using PHP and I do not know where to start.
Please, give me example, guides or any information.
Thank you very much!
Niv

Comment: There is a short and a slightly longer answer to that,the short one is: "No" and the slightly longer one : "No, No it is not" (at least the client side / the app itself)

Comment: The only thing I can think of is PhoneGap but I've never used it as you still need a mac to create the app for iOS: http://phonegap.com/

Comment: I believe your only option with PHP is to create a [web app](http://www.apple.com/webapps/)

Comment: So what is this: http://www.sourcecodester.com/Tutorials/php/creating-iphone-application-php-using-ipfaces-framework.html
this framework don't can help me?

Comment: It will help you do part of the job but not all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an actual app store application? Or a mobile based website?

Sure, you can create a mobile based website with PHP.

Applications in the app store are written in Objective-C.

You can possibly try http://phonegap.com - it natively uses HTML and JavaScript, so all of your PHP will need to be accessed remotely using something like jQuerys `$.get` or `$.post` functions.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick reply.
 I am developing in PHP and I realized that it is possible to create an iPhone app based on a remote server that runs on PHP code

Comment: Yes, take a look at http://phonegap.com - you can use HTML and JavaScript and connect remotely to a PHP file like in my answer above :)

Comment: So what is this: http://www.sourcecodester.com/Tutorials/php/creating-iphone-application-php-using-ipfaces-framework.html
this framework don't can help me?

Comment: I haven't used this so I wouldn't be able to comment, if its something that looks appealing, give it a go: http://www.ipfaces.org/learnmore

Answer (score 2):

If you mean a *native* app that runs on the iPhone: no, this is not possible since the PHP interpreter is not available on iOS.

If you mean a *web application* that is implemented on a server: sure, just like any web application.

Comment: So what is this: http://www.sourcecodester.com/Tutorials/php/creating-iphone-application-php-using-ipfaces-framework.html
this framework don't can help me?

Comment: @Niv: From their website: _Each iPFaces application consists of two main parts: Thin iPFaces client for mobile devices [and] The server part with application logic and definition of iPFaces views_ This means that there's a small native part which accesses a server that has the logic. The server logic can be written in PHP, but you still cannot write a 100% native app with PHP using this framework.

Comment: See [this page](http://www.ipfaces.org/node/76) for details.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create an iPhone App from PHP. iOS Apps are developed in Objective-C.

What you can do though would be to develop a webapp in php. It has the main advantage to be available for many platforms (PC/Mac, Android, iOS devices ...)